# System stats on desktop wallpaper

Tags: macos, desktop, statistics

I am looking for an app similar to conky on Linux that will allow me to display various system stats and style them right on my desktop wallpaper.

I am only able to find things like iStats which have menubar interactive items but I don't really want that, but something that will allow me to put various stuff right on the Desktop. Does this exist? Something like [this](https://ixquick-proxy.com/do/spg/show_picture.pl?l=english&rais=1&oiu=https%3A%2F%2Fforum.manjaro.org%2Fuploads%2Fdefault%2Foriginal%2F2X%2Fa%2Fab995140eb45496b45423765f96494ab46376387.jpg&sp=32ce100e11ef195c1ceecc4284929487)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[GeekTool](https://www.tynsoe.org/v2/geektool/) is what you need to accomplish this on the mac.

**Addendum:** Looks like [Uebersicht](http://tracesof.net/uebersicht/) is an another alternative.